# Benefits of Rails namespaced isolated Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, namespaces, rails-engines

I have 2 Rails applications mounting a `Core` Engine. The Engine is used here to group common code between Rails applications (they have very similar business logic but views and some other things differ).

The `Core::Engine` holds:

- common models
- common controllers and actions
- common libs
- common routes

Rails applications holds:

- specific models
- specific controllers or existing controller actions
- specific libs
- specific routes

Since I own the Core Engine and the Rails applications, I was wondering about the benefits of using `isolate_namespace Core`.

Namespacing the Engine will avoid name collision but since my Engine is not meant to be mounted elsewhere, should I care ?

Moreover, namespacing is great but do not play well with routes since I would have to add `core` or `main_app` to every url helpers.

**Question: Should I care about Engine namespacing in the case where the Engine is designed to DRY up common Rails application codebase ?**

Comment: Hi Pierre-Louis, i'm playing with engine for one of my apps and i'm asking the same question. Have you found something since you asked this question?

Comment: Hey, I actually went without namespace and it makes life easier for this particular case. However, for another project I only used the engine to hold shared models. I decided to namespace the engine to avoid class name collision but did not care about namespaced routes in this case.